# Looping with tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

I have some data from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_Red_Hot_Chili_Peppers_band_members&action=edit&section=4):

```
RHCP_data
                V1              V2              V3           V4
1       bar:kiedis from:01/01/1983 till:01/11/1986 color:vocals
2       bar:kiedis from:01/12/1986        till:end color:vocals
3         bar:flea from:01/01/1983        till:end   color:bass
4        bar:smith from:03/12/1988        till:end  color:drums
5  bar:klinghoffer from:01/10/2009        till:end   color:lead
6       bar:slovak from:01/01/1983 till:01/12/1983   color:lead
7       bar:slovak from:01/02/1985 till:25/06/1988   color:lead
...
...
```

I am trying to use `tidyr` to remove variable names and this works great:

```
separate(RHCP_data, "V1", into = c("a", "b"), sep = ":")[2]

             b
1       kiedis
2       kiedis
3         flea
4        smith
5  klinghoffer
6       slovak
7       slovak
...
...
```

I would like to understand why this does not work.

```
for(i in 1:4){
  RHCP_data[,i] <- separate(RHCP_data, paste0("V", i), into = c("a", "b"), sep = ":")[2][,1]
}
```

and I get this error:

```
Error: Invalid column specification
```

Obviously the dataset is small so it is not a problem in this situation but I feel there is something about `tidyr` or loops I don't understand. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass columns as variable you need to use `separate_` instead of `separate`.

And if you want to use a for loop, I would recommend:

```
lst = lapply(seq(ncol(df)), function(x) {
    separate_(df, paste0('V', x), into = paste0(c("a", "b"), x), sep = ":")[x:(x+1)][,2]
}) 

data.frame(setNames(lst, names(df)))
#           V1         V2         V3     V4
#1      kiedis 01/01/1983 01/11/1986 vocals
#2      kiedis 01/12/1986        end vocals
#3        flea 01/01/1983        end   bass
#4       smith 03/12/1988        end  drums
#5 klinghoffer 01/10/2009        end   lead
#6      slovak 01/01/1983 01/12/1983   lead
#7      slovak 01/02/1985 25/06/1988   lead
```

Comment: Great thank you. Do you know why there are two functions?

Comment: Also for the anyone else with this sort of problem this is the line I used in the end `RHCP_data[,i] <- separate_(RHCP_data, paste0("V", i), into = c("a", "b"), sep = ":")[i+1]`
}

Comment: there are two functions ofr this purpose: passing columns names as variable! By the way the for loop you use modifies the data.frame at each iteration. Beware this will enter in conflict with indices! It's better to consider your function does not operate directly on your original dataframe but create another one - as in my proposal.

Answer (score 3):

We can simply use `cSplit` without any loop.

```
library(splitstackshape)
DT <- cSplit(RHCP_data, 1:ncol(RHCP_data), ':')
DT[, seq(2, ncol(DT), by=2), with=FALSE]
#            V1_2       V2_2       V3_2   V4_2
#  1:      kiedis 01/01/1983 01/11/1986 vocals
#2:      kiedis 01/12/1986        end vocals
#3:        flea 01/01/1983        end   bass
#4:       smith 03/12/1988        end  drums
#5: klinghoffer 01/10/2009        end   lead
#6:      slovak 01/01/1983 01/12/1983   lead
#7:      slovak 01/02/1985 25/06/1988   lead
```